# Cant able to sync the variables inside a Threads android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
Boolean timer = false;

@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            downloadmanagerstart();
            System.out.println("return");

            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {
                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(download_id);

                Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                if (cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    downloading = false;
                }
                cursor.close();
                publishProgress(bytes_downloaded, bytes_total);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final int bytes_downloaded = values[0];
            System.out.println(bytes_downloaded
                    + " Downloaded 1");

            int bytes_total = values[1];
            int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);
            String totaldownload_str = android.text.format.Formatter
                    .formatFileSize(MainActivity.this, bytes_downloaded);
            current_tvm.setText(totaldownload_str);
            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

            if (!timer) {
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        t = new Timer();
                        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        System.out.println(bytes_downloaded
                                                + " Downloaded 2");
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }, 0, 1000);

                    }
                };
                thread.start();
                timer = true;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I have put two `System.out.println(bytes_downloaded+ " Downloaded 1");` in onProgress and`System.out.println(bytes_downloaded+ " Downloaded 2");` inside a thread on onProgress. The vale of `bytes_downloaded` is always 0 inside the thread why is this happening. I wanted it to be sync every second with the value `bytes_downloaded` in onProgress. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its 0 because its a final variable.  Once its set, it can't change.  So it will always be what you initially set it to.  If you want to pass data like that use a member variable of the class (with synchronization if necessary), not a final or method level variable.

Additionally, this approach isn't needed.  onProgressUpdate is already run on the UI thread-  that's the point of the function.  Why would you want to delay the UI update more, and why would you use such a convoluted way of doing so?  I think you really don't understand the concepts of how threads, timers, and AsyncTasks work, because this code makes 0 sense.

Comment: I wanted to calculate the download speed by kbps that's why I'm delaying the UI for each second. So that I can do some math and update download speed ever second. Ya, I accept u I'm just a learner or beginner or what ever it is. I don't know much about threads and async. Do u have any other way to find the download speed. Please ref my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664684/how-to-measure-the-download-speed-using-bytes-downloaded-and-bytes-total-android thanks for you support.

Comment: The standard way to get download speed would be to download a file and figure out how big it was, the time it took to download it, and divide the two.  You wouldn't use a timer or a thread to calculate the value, you'd do it as you were going in the download thread/task.

Comment: No, I want to update the speed in real-time while the file is being download. @Gabe Sechan .

Comment: THen you do it as you're downloading chunks.  In any case the thread and timer are unneeded and unwanted, you just need to update the UI in onProgressUpdated.